# OpenTbs convert html tags to MS Word tags

Tags: php, templates, ms-word, tinybutstrong, opentbs

I am using OpenTbs, http://www.tinybutstrong.com/plugins/opentbs/tbs_plugin_opentbs.html.

I have a template.docx and am able to replace fields with content but if the content has html code it is displayed in the document created by the template.

```
First list <br /> Second Line
```

I have tried to use:

```
$TBS->LoadTemplate('document.docx', OPENTBS_ALREADY_XML);
```

Thinking this would allow me to replace my html tags with ms office tags, but it just showed the MS Office tags in the document instead:

```
First Line<w:br/> Second Line
```

How do i convert the HTML tags into the MS Office XML equivalent.

Comment: I am pulling my hair out here, this should be very common the text that i replace the tags with [b.thetext] will have HTML styling that i want to turn into MS Word styling like bold and italic, i have found the MS Word equivalent but but can't put get them to function as code they are just outputted into the template as text...any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a conversion function for HTML to DOCX, then you can implement it in OpenTBS using a custom PHP function and parameter "onformat".

The following function only convert line breaks:

```
function f_html2docx($FieldName, &$CurrVal) {
  $CurrVal= str_replace('<br />', '<w:br/>', $CurrVal);
}
```

Use in the DOCX template :

```
[b.thetext;onformat=f_html2docx]
```

**About converting HTML to DOCX :**

Converting a formated text into another formated text is quite often a nightmare. That's why is it wise to store the pure data instead if formated data.

Converting HTML to DOCX is a real nightmare because the formating is not structured the same way.

For example, in HTML tags may me nested, like this:

```
<i> hello <b> this is important </b> to know </i>
```

In DOCX it will be presented as crossing, like this :

```
  <w:r>
    <w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr>
    <w:t>hello</w:t>
  </w:r>

  <w:r>
    <w:rPr><w:b/><w:i/></w:rPr>
    <w:t>this is important</w:t>
  </w:r>

  <w:r>
    <w:rPr><w:i/></w:rPr>
    <w:t>to know</w:t>
  </w:r>
```

I have no solution for converting tags other than line-breaks for now. Sorry for that.
And I think it would be quite difficult to code one.

Comment: I wonder did you end up finding a solution for this? I'm looking for something similar. I would only do basic formatting such as bold, underline & italics etc in HTML.

Comment: I've not worked on such a solution, I'm only reporting other's solutions.

Comment: Thanks, I think I am going to do this using PDF's instead as I know this will work. Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Skrol for your input on all my openTBS issues, just noticed that you are the creator of it, its a great class and what you said above was true after a day of plowing through learning the MS Word Format i had a brain wave and I am now able to produce the format that you specified above and can have bold italic and underline which is all i require, I hope this gives you a foundation to improve upon.

I basically noticed that in the example you put you just need an array of the styles which when you find a closing tag you remove from the style array. Each time you find a tag you need to close the `<w:r>` and create a new one, I have tested it and it works wonderfully.

```
class printClass {
    private static $currentStyles = array();    

    public function __construct() {}

    public function format($string) {
            if($string !=""){
            return preg_replace_callback("#<b>|<u>|<i>|</b>|</u>|</i>#",
                                        'printClass::replaceTags',
                                        $string);
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }


    private static function applyStyles() {

        if(count(self::$currentStyles) > 0 ) {

            foreach(self::$currentStyles as $value) {

                if($value == "b") {
                    $styles .= "<w:b/>";
                }   

                if($value == "u") {
                    $styles .= "<w:u w:val=\"single\"/>";
                }   

                if($value == "i") {
                    $styles .= "<w:i/>";
                }
            }

            return "<w:rPr>" . $styles . "</w:rPr>";
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }



    private static function replaceTags($matches) {

        if($matches[0] == "<b>") {
            array_push(self::$currentStyles, "b");
        }   

        if($matches[0] == "<u>") {
            array_push(self::$currentStyles, "u");
        }   

        if($matches[0] == "<i>") {
            array_push(self::$currentStyles, "i");
        }

        if($matches[0] == "</b>") {
            self::$currentStyles = array_diff(self::$currentStyles, array("b"));
        }   

        if($matches[0] == "</u>") {
            self::$currentStyles = array_diff(self::$currentStyles, array("u"));
        }   

        if($matches[0] == "</i>") {
            self::$currentStyles = array_diff(self::$currentStyles, array("i"));
        }

        return "</w:t></w:r><w:r>" . self::applyStyles() . "<w:t xml:space=\"preserve\">";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function f_html2docx($currVal) {

    // handling <i> tag

    $el = 'i';
    $tag_open  = '<' . $el . '>';
    $tag_close = '</' . $el . '>';
    $nb = substr_count($currVal, $tag_open);

    if ( ($nb > 0) && ($nb == substr_count($currVal, $tag_open)) ) {
        $currVal= str_replace($tag_open,  '</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:i/></w:rPr><w:t>', $currVal);
        $currVal= str_replace($tag_close, '</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>', $currVal);
    }

    // handling <b> tag

    $el = 'b';
    $tag_open  = '<' . $el . '>';
    $tag_close = '</' . $el . '>';
    $nb = substr_count($currVal, $tag_open);

    if ( ($nb > 0) && ($nb == substr_count($currVal, $tag_open)) ) {
        $currVal= str_replace($tag_open,  '</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr><w:t>', $currVal);
        $currVal= str_replace($tag_close, '</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>', $currVal);
    }

    // handling <u> tag

    $el = 'u';
    $tag_open  = '<' . $el . '>';
    $tag_close = '</' . $el . '>';
    $nb = substr_count($currVal, $tag_open);

    if ( ($nb > 0) && ($nb == substr_count($currVal, $tag_open)) ) {
        $currVal= str_replace($tag_open,  '</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:rPr><w:u w:val="single"/></w:rPr><w:t>', $currVal);
        $currVal= str_replace($tag_close, '</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>', $currVal);
    }

    // handling <br> tag

    $el = 'br';
    $currVal= str_replace('<br />', '<w:br/>', $currVal);

    return $currVal;
}

public function f_handleUnsupportedTags($fieldValue){
    $fieldValue = strip_tags($fieldValue, '<b><i><u><br>');

    $fieldValue = str_replace('&nbsp;',' ',$fieldValue);
    $fieldValue = str_replace('<br>','<br />',$fieldValue);

    return $fieldValue;
}
```

Now call this function as:

```
$fieldVal = $this->f_html2docx($this->f_handleUnsupportedTags($fieldVal));
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60891725/edit) your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.