# Differences between command-line and GUI converting (*.html, *.odt, *.doc)

Tags: php, html, file, type-conversion

I took over the development of an application which enables users to download some reports.
The system set up is as follows :

- Create a *.html file with data retrieved by php.
- Copy all the content of the *.html file in a *.doc file (not a real *.doc file, just a *.html file with the extension ".doc").
- The *.doc is available in download.

I know that is a weird solution to create report files, and I had a lot of difficulties to set up the CSS to work great in the *.doc file.
For example, now I need to set up margins at 0cm, but of course, when I open the generated *.doc in a text-editor like OpenOffice, LibreOffice, MSWord, he's open in WEB mode CSS margins sets to 0cm works fine. But, the users needs to open the file in STANDARD mode (like a real *.doc file) and the don't want to make some actions to convert the document, or sets margins to 0 cm (...).

So, I've found the solution to convert the *.html OR *.doc file in *.odt, unzip the *.odt file, modify the file "styles.xml" which allows me to sets the "STANDARD" margins to 0cm, then, re-save as *.doc format. 
This solution works great, BUT, I've only achieve thi on my PC with the LibreOffice GUI.

When I try to convert the *.html or *.doc file in *.odt with any programm in command-line (even the LibreOffice convert module), the *.odt file is not the same as when I use the LibreOffice GUI. So I've try with other convertion script like :

- pandoc
- abiword
- ooconvert

So, is there a way to convert properly my *.html fil into *.odt file ?
Or another way which allows me to do what I want ?

Thanks.

**EDIT/SOLVED :**

Works with [JODConverter](http://artofsolving.com/opensource/jodconverter/guide) !!

Comment: There is a proper way of doing this... but you won't like it: get the open doctypes [for MS](http://www.worddocx.com) and [LibreOffice](http://help.libreoffice.org/3.4/Common/Transformation) and get an xml parser, or use [liveDocx](http://www.phplivedocx.org/) soon to be part of ZF - as references go, that's a good one. PS: by `you won't like it` I meant: you're going to have to rewrite a lot of code

Comment: I just need a script which permite me to convert properly an *.html file into a *.odt archive. I don't think that liveDocx is a solution because I'm not sure if he preserves HTML (question 4621430).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to preserve the HTML, I'd still maintain LiveDocx might just prove useful. I did some more digging, and stumbled on [phpdocx](http://www.phpdocx.com/archives/2158). On the bottom of the page there's a link that shows you how to embed HTML. 
Both LiveDocX and phpdocx offer examples on their respective sites. I suggest you browse through those.

SO showed up a few times, too: interesting questions might be:

- [OpenTbs convert html tags to MS Word tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315531/opentbs-convert-html-tags-to-ms-word-tags)
- [How can I convert a docx document to html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587216/how-can-i-convert-a-docx-document-to-html-using-php)

I know the latter is the opposite of what you're trying to do, but don't write it off just for that reason. Often, it's quite helpful to look at things from another perspective.

Since your last comment leads me to believe you haven't actually gotten round to coding (`I just need a script etc...`) I would like to say that SO is not a code generator. When you're done reading about phpdocx and livedocx, perhaps you should read [what makes a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

I found what you were looking for, I think, [here](http://corymathews.com/saving-a-php-file-as-a-word-document/). If you want to use the php-cli, my guess would be setting your script's output stream to a file, and using the headers found below (copy-paste from link).

```
    header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; Filename=SaveAsWordDoc.doc");
```

Sorry if I came across a bit harsh, with the remark on SO not being a code generator, and the link to 'what makes a good question'. Didn't mean to bash you.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, the previous example would only work as a download link: below a working script that turns out a .doc file, based on a html string:

```
#!/bin/php -n
<?php
    $opts = array('file'=>array('header'=>'Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word'."\r\n".'Content-type: application/vnd.ms-word'."\r\n"));
    $resource = stream_context_create($opts);
    $doc = fopen('asDoc.doc','w+',false,$resource);
    if (!$doc)
    {
        die('FFS');
    }
    $html='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">';
    $html .='<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\"><title>Foo</title></head><body><h1>Hello, world</h1></body></html>';
    fwrite($doc,$html);
    fclose($doc);
    exit();
?>
```

The headers are defined in the context stream, so the first two lines of code are crucial. As is the `<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=Windows-1252\">` meta tag. All else is pretty basic. 
All functions you need are here, so refer to their man pages for more info if you want to know what does what...

Best of luck

Comment: For my last comment, I thought you'll could be more precise on this point if you already use liveDocx. Then, my problem will be done if I had a script/function/software usable in command line AND which respect the *.odt format. I've already seen phpdocx documentation, but functions used to insert HTML code are only usable with the PRO version. (I'm French so I imagine that some words are not in their place :))

Comment: OK, I already have these 2 lines in my PHP script. At this point, when I open my *.doc file in a MSWord or MSWord-like software, he open the file in HTML mode (completely normal). Is why I need a *.html to *.odt convertor. I already said this, but it works when I reproduce my step with GUI interface of my text editor (open my *.html file, -> save as *.odt format -> rename in *.zip -> unzip it -> modify the file "styles.xml" -> rename in *.odt -> reopen in my text editor -> save as *.doc -> works perfectly.

Comment: For example, http://www.docx2doc.com/convert/html-to-odt.html do what I'm trying to do ! My problem is that I can't unzip the file produced by the converters that I've tried !

Comment: I have no idea at all as to what you're doing, post the code you have thusfar. I can do pretty much everything you're trying to achieve with this simple snippet of code. Could be I misinterpreted your question

Comment: No need of code I juste have a HTML file, that I intent to convert in ODT format.

Comment: In which case, the last script I provided will work just fine. OpenOffice, LibreOffice and MSOffice all will recognize it as an HTML formatted office document. I have tested it.. it works. why don't you try it?

Comment: Because it's what I already have :) ! You said : `it as an HTML formatted office document`, but I need it to open in Standard mode with margins to 0cm ! So the only solution I found to achieve this, is to convert my *.html file in *.odt then unzip it then...etc...

Comment: You can't simply convert html to odt with php. It is possible, no doubt about that, but most likely, it won't be worth the bother. Either use the HTML formatted file (your question states that this is the format in which the file will be sent anyway), or look into python cli convertors. Or turn one of many libs. Or try setting the margins to `0em`s rather then `0cm` - em's are generally speaking a safer bet anyhow.

Comment: Is why I've tried some converters, the file is correctly converted, but always in WEB mode, I need to convert it in standard mode (the same processus that : open in web mode, switch as standard mode,save).