# OpenTBS - hide image when does not exist

Tags: php, image, docx, opentbs

I have a list of images filled with url, or empty in some case.
I just want to display the images when the url exists, and not display the image when the url is not specified.
There is a very similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938030/opentbs-remove-image-when-replace-not-found), but not fully answered, so I am posting this again.

Here is my php array:

```
$myBlock = array(
  'description' => ...,
  'name' => ...,
  'photos' => 
    array (
      0 => string 'C:\path_to\pic_5491y.png'
      1 => string 'C:\path_to\pic_5491y.png'
      2 => string 'C:\path_to\pic_5491y.png'
      3 => int 0
      ...
      9 => int 0
      10 => int 0
    )
);
```

I then try to display the image inside a block (at the moment, I only try with the first photo)

```
[myBlock; block=begin]
     (the image I am trying to replace, or hide)
     [CODE]
[myBlock; block=end]
```

And here are what I have tried to put in the `[CODE]`, with what happens:

- `[myBlock.photos.0;ope=addpic;att=draw:image#xlink:href;when [myBlock.photos.0]!=0]`

  ==>> `Undefined property: clsTbsLocator::$PrevPosBeg`
- `[myBlock.photos.0;ope=changepic;from=[val];tagpos=inside;adjust;unique;]`
- `[myBlock.photos.0;ope=changepic;from=[val];tagpos=inside;adjust;unique; onshow; when[myBlock.photos.0] != 0]` (same as before but with the `when`, which in the end does not change anything)

  ==>> `The picture "0" that is supposed to be added because of parameter "ope=changepic" of the field [myBlock.photos.0] is not found.` (that is caused when the image has 0 as its url)
- `[onShow; if[myBlock.photos.0] != 0; then[myBlock.photos.0] :drawing; else ‘1’]`

  ==>> `[onShow; if0 != 0; then0 :drawing; else '1']` (just display that on the document)
- `[onshow; if[myBlock.photos.0] = 0 ; then ‘’ ; else from=[ myBlock.photos.0]; ope=changepic; tagpos=inside;adjust;unique]`

  ==>> no errors, but don't replace any images, even when set

Thanks a lot in advance, and let me know if you need more details !

**EDIT**

Skrol's suggestions works perpectly when I use

```
$TBS->MergeBlock('myBlock', $myBlock['photos']);
```

But I am actually trying to merge directly `$myBlock`, and therefore in my word document, trying to do a "double foreach"

I am failing creating a double block in my template (the reason is that I am trying to display some info before the photos.)

I am trying to do :

```
[myBlock; block=begin]
   [myBlock.description]   // => Display description before displaying the photos

   [myBlock.photos; block=begin]
   [myBlock.photos; block=end]
[myBlock; block=end]
```

But as soon as I add the second `myBlock.photos` so I could loop through them, I have this error: `in block's definition [myBlock...]: a least one tag with parameter 'block=end' is missing.`

**EDIT BIS**

After trying several things, with same code, I managed to get rid of the error, probably because of a bad hidden caracter somewhere. But it is now trying to display the second block, instead of creating a new `foreach`:

```
 This is description 1
 array
 array

 This is description 2
 array
 array

 ....
```

If that helps getting a better picture of what I am trying to achieve, here the equivalent I would use in `PHP`:

```
foreach( $myBlock as $myBlockKey => $myBlockData)
{
    echo $myBlockData['description'];
    echo $myBlockData['name'];
    ...

    foreach( $myBlockData['photos'] as $photoKey => $photoData)
    {
       echo $photoData['url'];
    }
}
```

Any idea about how to get this double block defined ???
I could not find any exemple in the doc, or anywhere else :(

Comment: What are you merging the block with ? I.e. what is your `MergeBlock()` command ?

Comment: Yes you are right, I am doing `$TBS->MergeBlock('myBlock', $myBlock);`

Comment: What does contain the item `$myBlock['extra_data'] ?` When you talk about URL do you mean the path of the image such as `'C:\path_to\pic_5491y.png'` ? You want several images merged at the end or just only one ?

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me Skrol !! The `extra_data` contains information that I display before the photos like `title`, `decription`, ... Then, if `$myBlock['photos']` has 3 elements, I want TBS to automatically displays the 3 photos. If it has 5 elements, to display these 5 photos, as the number of photos attached varies. And yes, by `URL` I meant the path, sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to merge the images stored in `$myBlock['photos']`, your code should be like this :

PHP :

```
$TBS->MergeBlock('myBlock', $myBlock['photos']);
```

DOCX :

```
[myBlock; block=begin; when 0!=[myBlock.val]]
   (the image I am trying to replace, or hide)
   [myBlock.val;ope=changepic;tagpos=after;adjust;unique;]
[myBlock; block=end]
```

Explanations :

- Command `MergeBlock()` does merge data structured as a record-set. That is a set of records having the same structure. In your snipped, only `$myBlock['photos']` is a record-set. Since each record is directly a value, you can use the virtual columns  `val` and `key` to reach the data.
- Parameter `when 0!=[myBlock.val]` makes the block section to be conditional. So only records with a value different from 0 will be displayed.
- Parameter `tagpos=after` should be used because the TBS tag is placed *after* the image.

Comment: Thank you for that Skrol, works really well if I merge `$myBlock['photos']`. I am now trying to assign `$myBlock` as specified in my EDIT, so basically trying in word to loop through `myBlock`, display few information, and the inside this loop, loop again through the `photos` and then show them. It is failing so far, I have few things I want to try tonight to fix it, I will let you know how it goes !

Comment: So as mentionned, I tried few more things, but with no success. Your exemple works really well, but only If I am trying to display an array of a depth of 1. As soon as I try to manipulate my original `$myBlock` which have general information on the 1st level, and some photos saved as a 2nd level array, I can't get anywhere with definiing a second block inside the first one (hope I make sense, and my edits help!) Do you have any ideas on how to declare and manipulate a block inside  another block ??

Comment: My post is becoming super messy, I will tidy it up to have a simple question with your answer, and create another post for this double loop issue. Thanks again !